# WiFi  is not been showing under available networks

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB as a live session user. 
I am facing problem with my Wi-Fi
When I select the panel applet, it doesn't shows up my wifi name but others of my neighbours.
On the other hand My wifi is working fine at the same time on other mobile devices and computers.

Please help me to access the internet wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a couple of reasons, your router is on channel 12 or 13 with `iw reg get` showing the wrong country- the USA isn't allowed to use 12 or 13.  Another issue might be if your router is on 5GHz and the linux driver for your wifi card doesn't support 5GHz yet

please go [wireless script info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108)

You can copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt file and use http://paste.ubuntu.com to upload and paste the new URL in your question

Comment: Well,I may b lucky.it was working well and good when I restarted the system after a while. Thnks for help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your wifi network isn't hidden. If its hidden go to the top right corner of the screen select the wifi icon and then connect to a hidden wifi network.